# How to derive the formula 13 in the Xavier Initialization paper

Tags: neural-network, variance, gradient, glorot-initialization

How to derive the formula 13 in the Xavier Initialization paper [Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) from the formula 6?

[image]